Regular expression to validate repeating comma-separated groups without trailing comma
I'm attempting to develop a regex to validate a comma-separated string with the following groups. Each group must have:

a word without characters ,= followed by
= character followed by
a word without characters ,=

The above group may be repeated after a , separator. A trailing , is not allowed
This is a valid string
LASTNPERIODS5=1

This is a valid string (repeating groups):
LASTNPERIODS5=1,AGE=Y34,ACTIVITY=AAA

This should be invalid because of the trailing comma:
LASTNPERIODS5=1,AGE=Y34,ACTIVITY=AAA,

This should be invalid because of the missing = in the 2nd group:
LASTNPERIODS5=1,AGEY34,ACTIVITY=AAA

My closest attempt so far is:
^(\\b\[^,=\]*\\b)=(\\b\[^,=\]*\\b)(,(\\b\[^,=\]*\\b)=(\\b\[^,=\]*\\b))?

However, it allows a trailing comma and only seems to match the first two groups so I assume the third is not validated.

What's with the backslashes before the square brackets, and the double backslash for \\b? That's not a useful regex at all.

Why not like ^\w+=\w+(?:,\w+=\w+)*$ See https://regex101.com/r/JS84pe/1

A canonical way to write the regex here would be:
^[^,=]+=[^=,]+(?:,[^,=]+=[^=,]+)*$

This means:

^ from the start of the string
[^,=]+=[^=,]+ match a word=word term
(?:

, then match comma followed by
[^,=]+=[^=,]+ another word=word term


)* zero or more times
$ end of the string

Note that if the "word" term strictly means regex worx characters, then the above pattern can be simplified to:
^\w+=\w+(?:,\w+=\w+)*$

as mentioned in the comments.

Hmm, now I'm curious. I might preprocess words with t = re.sub('[^,=]+', 'w', s) and then do re.fullmatch('w=w(?:,w=w)*', t). Can you tell whether that's a commonly used technique to handle repetitive subpatterns, or do people prefer repeating them or handling them some other way?

@nocomment See Capturing repeating subpatterns in Python regex

@WiktorStribiżew I don't see the connection, that just seems to be about something else.

Thanks for the elegant solution, I used the second expression that starts with ^\w+. If I may ask a follow-up: the second word may be a set separated by plus characters, e.g. LASTNPERIODS5=1,AGE=Y32+Y33+Y34,ACTIVITY=AAA+BBB. What would the expression be?

You may use: ^\w+=\w+(?:\+\w+)*(?:,\w+=\w+(?:\+\w+)*)*$ ... check the demo here: https://regex101.com/r/iPqN6J/1

@TimBiegeleisen Sir, you are a star. Thanks so much

Following regex might be suitable for your task:
^(?!.*,$)(\w+=[^,=]+)(,(?!.*,$)\w+=[^,=]+)*$

Explaination:

^ starts the string
(?!.*,$) ensures that there are no trailing commas
(\w+=[^,=]+) ensures that word is followed by a equal sign and more words after equal except = or ,
(,(?!.*,$)\w+=[^,=]+)* this matches more groups which are seperated by single comma and other similar groups.
$ ends the string

This regex will match the whole grop along with the the individual group inside the string. Following image might be of help to you.


won't this be much simplier?
def validate_string(string):
    spl = string.split(',')
    return all(word.count('=') == 1 for word in spl)

